# how to do looping in R

Tags: r, loops

Hey guys i want to do looping in R ; can anybody help me out

For eg i have sum of points and i want no of empid in 0-10 % of sum of points and so on ;how to do in R

For eg I have data as

```
empid               sumofpoints
  1                       10
  2                       30
```

I want data as

```
percentageofsumpoints       countofempid
   0-10                        4
  11-20                        5
  21-30                        6
```

and so on....
How to do it in R ,do i have to install any package for it

Comment: you should add an example of some of the code you have tried so far so we can help you along, not do it for you

Comment: I'm not sure what work you've done thus far but a Google search would have helped you out. The R documentation is really quite good.

Answer (score 2):

No need to install package.See http://nunn.rc.fas.harvard.edu/groups/pica/wiki/1f131/

Simple for loop

```
 for (i in 1:10){
     print(i)
 }
```

In your example, asssuming your data is stored in a dataframe called `df`

```
res <- NULL
groups <- c(0,10,20,30,40,...)
for (i in 2:length(groups)){
    res <- rbind(res,c(paste(groups[i],groups[i-1],sep="-"),nrow(df[df$sumofpoints <= groups[i] & df$sumofpoints > groups[i-1],])))
}
```

You can also use `apply` functions if you want to avoid `for` statements. This example I have taken directly from the help files

```
 x <- cbind(x1 = 3, x2 = c(4:1, 2:5))
 dimnames(x)[[1]] <- letters[1:8]
 apply(x, 2, mean, trim = .2)
```

**EDIT** further to this [how to avoid loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225554/how-to-avoid-loops?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

For large dataset, refer to the package `foreach`. This allows for a sequential loop set-up using `%do%` or a parallel set-up (faster for large datasets) using `%dopar%`.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf

For parallel computing, be mindful that you will need a backend such as "doParallel" or "DoSNOW". There is also "doMC" which only works with operating systems that support the
fork system call (which means that Windows isn't supported).